# Function replacement of nftw

Tags: posix, file-traversal

ALL,

According to [this](https://linux.die.net/man/3/nftw), ntfw is obsolete in POSIX.1-2008.

Is there a replacement of this function? Or I should use something else across the board?

TIA!

Comment: I think you've misread the manpage.  *ftw()* is [obsolescent per POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftw.html#tag_16_180_07), with *ntfw()* as its recommended successor.

Comment: @pilcrow, that's the problem - the link I referenced does not give the replacement there. It just states `POSIX.1-2008 marks ftw() as obsolete`. So basically I should use nftw() everywhere, right?

Answer (score 1):

From the link you cited:

> POSIX.1-2001, SVr4, SUSv1. POSIX.1-2008 marks **ftw()** as obsolete. ...
>
> On some systems ftw() will never use FTW_SL, on other systems FTW_SL occurs only for symbolic links that do not point to an existing file, and again on other systems ftw() will use FTW_SL for each symbolic link. **For predictable control, use nftw().**

My interpretation is that ftw was obsoleted in favor of nftw. So use that.

Personally, I would just implement my own. Every intro level CS textbook I've ever read covers filesystem traversal. I would use a fifo queue of dir handles and iterative breadth-first loop to avoid unnecessary function call overhead, both in the traversal and in the per-file hook (implemented as a function pointer in ftw).